# got to do or have to do?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> What does football got to do with French Gourmet. These are totally
> unrelated to each other.
>
> What does football have to do with French Gourmet. These are totally
> unrelated to each other.

Is got to do and have to do the same? I thought so, but I am not sure if "got to do" is idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard English the second would be correct and the first incorrect.

Alternatively you could use "What has football got to do with French Gourmet?"